# How can I use Mangopollo's IconicTileData to update the main tile of my application?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I write an app for Windows Phone 7/8. I want my default tile to look like WP8's one, so I use Mangopollo in such manner:

```
var tile = new IconicTileData
{
      Title = "WP Day",
      Count = 8,
      BackgroundColor = Colors.Transparent,
      IconImage = new Uri("/ApplicationIcon.png", UriKind.Relative),
      SmallIconImage = new Uri("/ApplicationIcon.png", UriKind.Relative),
      WideContent1 = "WP Developer Day",
      WideContent2 = "use Windows Phone 8 features",
      WideContent3 = "on Windows Phone 7 apps"
}.ToShellTileData();;

var tile2 = new StandardTileData
{
    Title = "E",
    Count = 9
};

ShellTile.ActiveTiles.FirstOrDefault().Update(tile);
```

But it does not effect. When I want to update "first" tile with *tile* object (IconicTileData) does not any effect. But when I use *tile2* object the tile is updating. Any ideas?

I saw thats possible in a few apps, for example TinyDO.

Answer (score 0):

Tried this code after modification from link : http://wp.qmatteoq.com/tag/mangopollo/

and it works.. it is this line which does the trick:

```
Uri navigationUri = new Uri("/MainPage.xaml?Id=5", UriKind.Relative);
private void OnCreateWideTileClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (true)
    {
        var tile = new IconicTileData
        {
            Title = "WP Day",
            Count = 8,
            BackgroundColor = Colors.Transparent,
            IconImage = new Uri("/Assets/Tiles/IconicTileMediumLarge.png", UriKind.Relative),
            SmallIconImage = new Uri("/Assets/Tiles/IconicTileSmall.png", UriKind.Relative),
            WideContent1 = "WP Developer Day",
            WideContent2 = "use Windows Phone 8 features",
            WideContent3 = "on Windows Phone 7 apps"
        }.ToShellTileData();

        ShellTileExt.Create(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml?Id=5", UriKind.Relative), tile, true);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("This is Windows Phone 7");
    }
}

private void OnUpdateTileClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (Utils.IsWP8)
    {
        IconicTileData tile = new IconicTileData
        {
            WideContent1 = "This is the new content",
            WideContent2 = "The tile has been updated",
            WideContent3 = "with success"
        };

        Uri navigationUri = new Uri("/MainPage.xaml?Id=5", UriKind.Relative);
        ShellTile.ActiveTiles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.NavigationUri == navigationUri).Update(tile);
    }
}
```